# No coverage in 'all classes in scope' in Intellij

Tags: intellij-idea, code-coverage, jacoco

In Intellij IDEA 14.1.5 Community edition, I imported maven to get coverage from jacoco.exec file. Steps followed

1. right click on imported module.
2. select Analyze-->Show Converage Data.
3. provided valid jacoc.exec file and click 'show selected'

Instead of coverage i'm getting error as **no coverage in 'all classes in scope'**

can anybody suggest what is wrong?

Comment: Can you try to downgrade jacoco to 7.4.x or earlier?

Comment: I'm using Jacoco 0.7.8 and seeing this in IntelliJ as well

Answer (score 27):

I had the same thing happen to me.

**I was able to fix this by going to "Edit Configurations", to the "Code Coverage" tab.**

I'm not sure what caused it, but the wrong package namespace was listed there. I updated the entry there and my subsequent test run with code coverage succeeded.

Comment: just FYI for me this happened because the package structure of my test code and my productive code didn't match. So my class was in foo.bar.baz.myclass and testclass was in foo.bar.mytestclass

Answer (score 17):

It happens if your test class and class to test are in different package structures.

My test class was in:

```
com.tools.api
```

Class to be tested was in:

```
com.tools.ws
```

Once I've corrected the pattern as `com.tools.*` in the code coverage tab, I was able to see coverage results.

Comment: Thank you!  It turns out that IntelliJ makes a poor choice about what coverage you want to see when you choose to only run one test.  It creates a new Run Configuration when you choose to run only one test class or one package of test classes.  It defaults to only recording coverage for classes that are in the same package as the test.  That caused a problem for me since I sub-package my tests sometimes. This answer clued me into that fact.

Comment: Matching the classes and test classes is probably the best for consistency and readability anyway

Comment: Thanks for the solution. I like to add another packacke named "unit" or "integration" because e.g. I test the service class as a unit test ( with moching the db ) and as integration test ( with a test db). I know this can be deone with naming the class MyServiceUnitTest and MyServiceIntegrationTest but I like the additional strucuture. So defining the included packe solves the problem.

Answer (score 4):

I had the same problem and found solution [here](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/configuring-code-coverage-measurement.html).

> In the Code Coverage tab, define the following options:
>
> Specify the scope to measure code coverage for. Do one of the following:
> To specify a class, click the Add Class button.
>
> To specify a package, click the Add Package button.

Answer (score 4):

I was able to fix this issue by:

1. Open `Edit Configurations` menu
2. Click on `Modify Options` > `Coverage settings` > `Specify classes and packages`
   [image: screenshot of run configuration settings]
3. In the new box that appears, click on the plus to add a package
   [image]
4. Select a high level package from the project

Comment: This worked in my case. thanks!